# Check if date is between a range of dates in excel

Tags: excel, formulas

I was wondering if someone could help me with this. I am not even sure if it is even possible. I have done a lot of research with no luck. Please see attached picture for reference.

Transition meeting column means the meeting needs to happen between those 2 dates. now six month and annual review are also meetings. This transition range is possible dates to have the meeting the thing is that this transition needs to happen at the same time as either six month or annual. So I would like to display instead of the range in transition have excel do the formula to check where the meeting needs to take place. for example on row 1 the transition needs to happen between april and september 2016. in this case it would have to be with the annual in June.. so I would like row 1 to display June 2016 instead of April 2016 - September 2016..

Hopefully this makes sense..

Thank you,

[image]

Comment: Are the cells with dates displayed (except for "Transition Meeting") formatted as actual dates? If they are comparing dates is just comparing them numerically ie `=IF(AND(B2>=H2,C2<=H2),H2,G2)`. If a date is older its serial value will be lower. Not quite getting your question.

Answer (score 0):

This will be much easier to do this if you can split out the column 'Transition Meeting' into two columns.

Assuming that everything in 'Transition Meeting' is in column F, 'Six Month Review' is in column G, 'Annual Review' is in column H and they are all in the same format, add three columns and then paste in the first one:

```
=LEFT(F2,FIND("-",F2)-2)*1
```

and copy down; paste in the second one:

```
=MID(F2,FIND("-",F2)+2,9999999)*1
```

This will extract the start and end dates from 'Transition meeting'. (Note that when you initially press Enter, you may get something like '43567'. If this happens, just format the cell as 'Date' to get a normal date.)

Then you just need an IF statement in the third column to check which review you need. See my screenshot below for more help - yellow cells are the ones I've added to your data. The top cells show the data and the bottom cells the formulae I've used.

[image: excel example]